# How to insert my first and subsequent rows into a my database for android project

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have a `DatabaseHelper` class that builds all my tables and handles queries, etc.

However, one thing stumps me.

I have a `checklist` table with the following columns:

```
checklist_id, int, primary key
start_time,   text
end_time,     text
```

This is my "insertChecklist()" method, that inserts a row into the table:

```
public long insertChecklist(Checklist checklist){
        // Get reference of the ChecklistDB database
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // Make values to be inserted
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ChecklistContract._ID, checklist.getId());
        values.put(ChecklistContract.COLUMN_NAME_START_TIME, checklist.getStartTime());
        values.put(ChecklistContract.COLUMN_NAME_END_TIME, checklist.getEndTime());

        // Insert the new row, returning the primary key value of the new row
        long newRowId;
        newRowId = db.insert(
                ChecklistContract.TABLE_NAME,
                null, //COLUMN_NAME_NULLABLE (set to null to not insert new row where there are no values)
                values);

        // close database transaction
        db.close();

        return newRowId;
    }
```

So I utilize this function as follows:

1. I create a `Checklist` object
2. I pass it into my `insertChecklist()` method

However, how do I know what to make the id in my Checklist object?

```
Checklist checklist = new Checklist(id??, startTime, endTime); 
// the "id" needs to be the equal to the last id in the table, plus 1

insertChecklist(checklist);
```

Does anyone have experience with SQLite databases that could help me with this? Am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: @RRR No errors, it's just more of a logic question on my end. I don't know how to insert rows because I don't know how to figure out what checklist_id I need to use based off what is already in the table.

Comment: add in AUTO_INCREMENT in your id column might help. Look here for more info [SQL Auto Increment](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp). With auto increment id, you don't have to generate id in your code, sqlite will handle it for you. You only have to insert start time and end time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `insert()` function returns the `rowid` of the new row.

If your table has an [autoincrementing ID](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), i.e., an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT column, then this is the same as the `rowid`.

In that case, to automatically assign a new value, do *not* put any ID value into the `ContentValues`, and set the ID of your object to the value returned by `insert()`:

```
public void insertChecklist(Checklist checklist) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ChecklistContract.COLUMN_NAME_START_TIME, checklist.getStartTime());
        values.put(ChecklistContract.COLUMN_NAME_END_TIME,   checklist.getEndTime());

        long id;
        id = db.insertOrThrow(ChecklistContract.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        checklist.setId(id);
    } finally {
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question!